# Seems to be .htaccess mod_rewrite issue on Laravel site - proper setup?

Tags: apache, laravel, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a Laravel 5.2 site. My .htaccess file is under public folder. I have the following .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^category/(.*)/(.*) guitar-lessons/$2/$1 [NC,R=301]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

This is how previous developers set it up. I am the site owner and am not exactly a web developer, but am fairly familiar with web development, server configuration, etc.

I changed url structure on my site and so I added one line to the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^category/(.*)/(.*) guitar-lessons/$2/$1 [NC,R=301]
```

So a link of form site.com/category/1/scales should be rewritten to site.com/guitar-lessons/scales/1

I added rewrite logging, and when testing this on localhost, I see this in error log:

```
add per-dir prefix: guitar-lessons/scales/1 -> /Library/WebServer/Documents/mysite/public/guitar-lessons/scales/1
    [Wed Jul 26 00:32:47.469564 2017] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 10084] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client ::1:58524] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#7fd89e81f6f8][rid#7fd89f00aaa0/initial] [perdir /Library/WebServer/Documents/mysite/public/] explicitly forcing redirect with http://localhost/Library/WebServer/Documents/mysite/public/guitar-lessons/scales/1
    [Wed Jul 26 00:32:47.469568 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 10084] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client ::1:58524] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#7fd89e81f6f8][rid#7fd89f00aaa0/initial] [perdir /Library/WebServer/Documents/mysite/public/] add path info postfix: http://localhost/Library/WebServer/Documents/mysite/public/guitar-lessons/scales/1 -> http://local$
    [Wed Jul 26 00:32:47.469572 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 10084] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client ::1:58524] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#7fd89e81f6f8][rid#7fd89f00aaa0/initial] [perdir /Library/WebServer/Documents/mysite/public/] applying pattern '^(.*)/$' to uri 'http://localhost/Library/WebServer/Documents/mysite/public/guitar-lessons/scales/1/1/s$
    [Wed Jul 26 00:32:47.469578 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 10084] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client ::1:58524] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#7fd89e81f6f8][rid#7fd89f00aaa0/initial] [perdir /Library/WebServer/Documents/mysite/public/] add path info postfix: http://localhost/Library/WebServer/Documents/mysite/public/guitar-lessons/scales/1 -> http://local$
    [Wed Jul 26 00:32:47.469582 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 10084] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client ::1:58524] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#7fd89e81f6f8][rid#7fd89f00aaa0/initial] [perdir /Library/WebServer/Documents/mysite/public/] applying pattern '^' to uri 'http://localhost/Library/WebServer/Documents/mysite/public/guitar-lessons/scales/1/1/scales'
    [Wed Jul 26 00:32:47.469594 2017] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 10084] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client ::1:58524] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#7fd89e81f6f8][rid#7fd89f00aaa0/initial] [perdir /Library/WebServer/Documents/mysite/public/] rewrite 'http://localhost/Library/WebServer/Documents/mysite/public/guitar-lessons/scales/1/1/scales' -> 'index.php'
    [Wed Jul 26 00:32:47.469598 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 10084] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client ::1:58524] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#7fd89e81f6f8][rid#7fd89f00aaa0/initial] [perdir /Library/WebServer/Documents/mysite/public/] add per-dir prefix: index.php -> /Library/WebServer/Documents/mysite/public/index.php
    [Wed Jul 26 00:32:47.469605 2017] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 10084] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client ::1:58524] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#7fd89e81f6f8][rid#7fd89f00aaa0/initial] [perdir /Library/WebServer/Documents/mysite/public/] strip document_root prefix: /Library/WebServer/Documents/mysite/public/index.php -> /index.php
    [Wed Jul 26 00:32:47.469608 2017] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 10084] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client ::1:58524] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#7fd89e81f6f8][rid#7fd89f00aaa0/initial] [perdir /Library/WebServer/Documents/mysite/public/] internal redirect with /index.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
    [Wed Jul 26 00:32:47.472007 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 10084] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client ::1:58524] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#7fd89e81f6f8][rid#7fd89e87fbf0/initial/redir#1] [perdir /Library/WebServer/Documents/mysite/public/] strip per-dir prefix: /Library/WebServer/Documents/mysite/public/index.php -> index.php
    [Wed Jul 26 00:32:47.472020 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 10084] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client ::1:58524] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#7fd89e81f6f8][rid#7fd89e87fbf0/initial/redir#1] [perdir /Library/WebServer/Documents/mysite/public/] applying pattern '^category/(.*)/(.*)' to uri 'index.php'
    [Wed Jul 26 00:32:47.472033 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 10084] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client ::1:58524] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#7fd89e81f6f8][rid#7fd89e87fbf0/initial/redir#1] [perdir /Library/WebServer/Documents/mysite/public/] strip per-dir prefix: /Library/WebServer/Documents/mysite/public/index.php -> index.php
    [Wed Jul 26 00:32:47.472038 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 10084] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client ::1:58524] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#7fd89e81f6f8][rid#7fd89e87fbf0/initial/redir#1] [perdir /Library/WebServer/Documents/mysite/public/] applying pattern '^(.*)/$' to uri 'index.php'
    [Wed Jul 26 00:32:47.472044 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 10084] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client ::1:58524] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#7fd89e81f6f8][rid#7fd89e87fbf0/initial/redir#1] [perdir /Library/WebServer/Documents/mysite/public/] strip per-dir prefix: /Library/WebServer/Documents/mysite/public/index.php -> index.php
    [Wed Jul 26 00:32:47.472048 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 10084] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client ::1:58524] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#7fd89e81f6f8][rid#7fd89e87fbf0/initial/redir#1] [perdir /Library/WebServer/Documents/mysite/public/] applying pattern '^' to uri 'index.php'
    [Wed Jul 26 00:32:47.472060 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 10084] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client ::1:58524] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#7fd89e81f6f8][rid#7fd89e87fbf0/initial/redir#1] [perdir /Library/WebServer/Documents/mysite/public/] strip per-dir prefix: /Library/WebServer/Documents/mysite/public/index.php -> index.php
    [Wed Jul 26 00:32:47.472064 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 10084] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client ::1:58524] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#7fd89e81f6f8][rid#7fd89e87fbf0/initial/redir#1] [perdir /Library/WebServer/Documents/mysite/public/] applying pattern '.*' to uri 'index.php'
```

As you can see, something odd is going on. At first all is well, but then note this:

```
add path info postfix: http://localhost/Library/WebServer/Documents/guitar-dreams/public/guitar-lessons/scales/1 -> http://localhost/Library/WebServer/Documents/guitar-dreams/public/guitar-lessons/scales/1/1/scales
```

This adding path info is messing it up. Any idea how to correct this in the simplest way possible? I really want to just keep .htaccess in public folder and not make this complicated...

Thanks!